# Unshareable Database in USA

Tags: usa, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, research, research-papers

Is there a specific list of data in the USA which includes what all is not to be shared on an open data platform to the public? If yes, where can it be found? It is popularly known as a 'negative list' as well.